# Adding UIButton to MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I've a custom class of `MKAnnotationView` in which I'm trying to add 8 button to the annotation in a circular fashion.I've added the buttons.Their postion in the view is perfectly fine but the action of the buttons doesn't get called.Why the action is not getting called and what is the solution.

```
-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated`
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    if(selected)
    {
        UIView *circularView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-55, -55, 110, 110)];
        circularView.tag = 1000;

        UIButton *btn1;
        UIButton *btn2;
        UIButton *btn3;
        UIButton *btn4;
        UIButton *btn5;
        UIButton *btn6;
        UIButton *btn7;
        btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn1];
        btn1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                       initWithTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [btn1 addGestureRecognizer:tap];

        btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn2];

        btn3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn3];

        btn4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn4];

        btn5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn5];

        btn6 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn6];

        btn7 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [circularView addSubview:btn7];

        [btn1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn5 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn6 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn7 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"message-icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        CGPoint point = CGPointMake(55, 55);
        btn1.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 15.00, point.y - 55.00, 30, 30);
        btn2.frame = CGRectMake(point.x + 16.27, point.y - 39.94, 30, 30);
        btn3.frame = CGRectMake(point.x + 24.00, point.y - 06.10, 30, 30);
        btn4.frame = CGRectMake(point.x + 02.36, point.y + 21.04, 30, 30);
        btn5.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 32.36, point.y + 21.04, 30, 30);
        btn6.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 54.00, point.y - 06.10, 30, 30);
        btn7.frame = CGRectMake(point.x - 46.27, point.y - 39.94, 30, 30);
        [self addSubview:circularView];
    }
    else
    {
        [[self viewWithTag:1000] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
-(void)buttonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{

}
```

Comment: it wud b better if u posted some code ....

Comment: There is nothing much in the code.I just added all buttons on a  UIView and added the UIView to the MKAnnotationView.

Comment: then either ur annotation is not getting clicked maybe theres some view on it or they get disabled .... cant tell u anything certainly u c ...

Comment: What happens on the tap of buttons? annotation view get disappear?

Comment: actually I add all the buttons when the annotation get clicked and the button have been added successfully.I'm sure that there is no view in between.

Comment: yes the annotation view get disappeared because I've written in the method -(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
to disappear on next click on the annotation view.

Comment: OK. I faced similar problem with custom annotation, I solved it by using UITapGestureRecognizer.

Comment: Did you added the UITapGesture on the UIButton ?

Comment: Yes. Add Gesture on UIButtons which you added on annotation view. Same as Paras Joshi given in answer.

Comment: This problem has not been solved yet.Please suggest any solution if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution for this.So,I think this is not possible with this method.If still some one wants to implement this functionality then one has to use draw them on an UIiew whose user interaction is disabled.Add this UIView on the MKMapView. Use the method `didSelectAnnotationView` with `[mapView deselectAnnotation:view.annotation animated:YES];`if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add the `UIButton` like bellow and call it's event with `UITapGestureRecognizer`.. See the Example bellow...

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
        viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView 
            dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier: @"pin"];
    if (annView == nil)
    {
        annView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                      reuseIdentifier:@"pin"] autorelease];

        annView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50);

        UIButton *pinButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        pinButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 140, 28);
        pinButton.tag = 10;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
            initWithTarget:self action:@selector(btnPinTap:)];
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [pinButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [tap release];

        [annView addSubview:pinButton]; 
    }

    annView.annotation = annotation;

    UIButton *pb = (UIButton *)[annView viewWithTag:10];
    [pb setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return annView;
}

- (void) btnPinTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) gestureRecognizer.view;
    MKAnnotationView *av = (MKAnnotationView *)[btn superview];
    id<MKAnnotation> ann = av.annotation;
    NSLog(@"btnPinTap: ann.title=%@", ann.title);
}
```

Just add Delegate in `.h` file ..

`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

and just put this bellow method in your `.m` file...

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
        shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
            :(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: @Shubham you try this?? and also check its UserInterectuion property is true

Comment: Yes,I already tried the similar thing.But whose user interaction need to be enabled ?

Comment: your button like yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Comment: [circularView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:circularView]; add this line at and where you add this circularView

Comment: -(void)buttonTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  NSLog(@"\n\n Button Clicked Here");
} you check with this ??

Comment: I put NSLog now.but still the same result

Comment: oh then its right dude and you add this gesture for btn1 only.. and also try to set the different title for these whole button so you can see that its called or not..

Comment: @Shubham for it you add the GeastureDelegate in .h file like UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h file?

Comment: yes,I set the delegates but still not getting the desired result :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22058/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-shubham)

Answer (score 0):

It's because circularView is outside the annotation frame. Expanding self.frame to the size of circularView will make it work. But, depending on other things, pins etc, it might not look great.