# Unable to fire click event of UIButton in custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: objective-c

I am working on custom callout bubble, and i successfully created custom bubble, but issue      is that there are no of buttons inside the bubble, which are not getting touch.

see attached screenshot.

Please help me

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14132885/1160493

Comment: I had already tried this link, can you please suggest me another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.
In your custom `MKAnnotation` class, add this method.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.calloutView];

    CGPoint visitedButtonPosition = [touch locationInView:_visitedButton];
    BOOL isPointInsideVisitedButton = [_visitedButton pointInside:visitedButtonPosition withEvent:nil];
    if(isPointInsideVisitedButton)
    {
    [self.tapDelegate yourVisitedAction];
    }
}
```

Using custom delegate, initiate the action in your view controller class.